# How do I create an UIImageView with a diagonal Cut?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an app with an imageView that needs to have a diagonal cut. Here is a picture for reference [image: image of diagonal imageView.] I am not sure how to code this. I suspect a mask is needed, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

So upon further examination and some thought I realized that all I needed was to draw a line in between the two views. Then I can just have the line move with the text view as it scrolls.

Comment: can u tell me how can i achieve this kind of layout ,i am not at all understanding . Please help me